# Native C library in Kotlin-JVM/Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-native

Is there any way to use native C libraries in kotlin-jvm without JNI?
The use case is simple, I want to use kotlin wrappers around native libraries like SQLite without painful JNI work. I didn't find anything in samples except the one with NativeActivity.

Everything that I found about the topic is this thread, which is not very detailed: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/interoperability-between-kotlin-native-and-kotlin-jvm/5943

Comment: Sqlite on Android shouldn't need JNI...?

Answer (score 2):

As Eugene pointed out, its not possible, not without JNI.  I've used [Djinni](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni) from the good folks at Dropbox.  While not a silver bullet, it really does reduce the pain of JNI work.  I should also point out its designed to work with C++, not C per se.  But perhaps its still of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible right now. You either use Kotlin/JVM or Kotlin/Native. There is interop for C libraries in Kotlin/Native.

Also, there is Kotlin multiplatform project to bind SQLite https://medium.com/@kpgalligan/sqlite-on-kotlin-native-9bcf47854cae